# Connecting to coherence from Oracle Stream Analytics

Tags: oracle-coherence, oracle-streams

I'm trying to implement below scenario.

1. Data should be pushed to Oracle coherence from DB.
2. This coherence should be accessible to Oracle Stream Analytics to apply some rules.

I'm able to connect to the coherence from command prompt by executing `coherence.cmd` file. When I execute this file, it is connecting to existing coherence.

But when I'm trying to create Coherence Cache stream in oracle stream analytics , I'm getting below warning and the operation is timed out.

> 2016-08-18 10:17:27.693/1423.868 Oracle Coherence GE 12.1.3.0.0
>    (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): This Member(Id=0,
>   Timestamp=2016-08-18 10:16:5
>   7.08, Address=192.168.1.150:55721, MachineId=4789, Location=site:,machine:,process:9376,
>   Role=BeaWlevsServer) has been attempting to joi n the cluster using
>   WKA list [/192.168.1.150:55720] for 30 seconds without success; this
>   could indicate a mis-configured WKA, or it may simply be the result of
>   a busy cluster or active failover.
>
> 2016-08-18 10:17:27.693/1423.868 Oracle Coherence GE 12.1.3.0.0
>    (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): Delaying formation of a new
>   cluster; waiting f or well-known nodes to respond

Can any one please tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

By default `coherence.cmd` uses multicast to discover running Coherence cluster (unless you somehow modified this script).

I don't know Oracle Stream Analytics, but from the logs you have provided I'm guessing that it tries to connect to Coherence cluster using well known address (WKA) and it seems that no Coherence node is available on the address `192.168.1.150:55720`. So make sure that Coherence member is running on `192.168.1.150:55720` or change configuration in Oracle Stream Analytics to connect to Coherence on different address (unfortunately, I can't help you with that).